# Computer folders backing up images/videos to Google Photos and those images/videos on Google Photos are not talking to each other

Tags: google-drive, google-photos, sync

If I have a file on my computer, like .txt document, in a folder backed to Google Drive (via the Google Drive app on my computer) and I edit this document using a text editor on my phone, the changes are applied to the cloud file and the file on my computer's local drive. The same is true the other way around; editing the copy on the computer's local drive edits the cloud copy.

I've backed a folder on my computer to Google Photos (not Drive) via the Google Drive app on my computer and the images and videos in it are now indeed in my Google Photos. However, when I delete/edit the copy of an image (or video) that is in that folder on my computer, the changes are not applied to the cloud copy of the image (the one in Google Photos), and when I edit/delete the cloud copy the changes don't apply to the local copy. Can I make them sync together?